# How to collect all response for each user in a nested map function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I have a data like below:

```
const Users = 
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": "person1",
      "information": [
        {
        "first_name": "Mike",
        "last_name": "Patty",
        "address": ["address1","address2"]
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Mike2",
          "last_name": "Patty2",
          "address": ["address1","address2"]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "person2",
      "information": [
        {
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "last_name": "Jerry",
        "address": ["address1","address2"]
        },
        {
          "first_name": "Tom2",
          "last_name": "Jerry2",
          "address": ["address1","address2"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

1. I would like to iterate users and add each user's information to the API database. `addInfo` request requires: `first_name`, `last_name` and `address` (`address` is array).
2. Each `this.APIservice.addInformation()` will return one  response, I will need the response later

**How do I collect all response from all `information` for the same users and get in a format like:**

```
// should return two object/array, each object/array collects all response from information for the same person.
person1:
["response from Mike Patty", "response from Mike2 Patty2"]
person2:
["response from Tom Jerry", "response from Tom2 Jerry2"]
```

here is what I am trying to code so far:

```
// add information 
const addUsers$ = forkJoin(

  Users.users.map(person => 
    person.information.map(info => 
      this.APIservice.addInformation(
        {
         firstName: info.first_name,
         lastName: info.last_name,
         address: info.address
        })
      )
    )
  );

otherFunction$. // this needs to run first
  .pipe(
  mergeMap(() => addUsers$)
  tap(console.log),
  // I need to manipulate res later here
  ).subscribe(() => console.log("finish"))
}
```

The error with current codes:

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate it like this.

```
Users.users.map(person=>{
      person.information.map(info => 
      this.APIservice.addInformation(
        {
         firstName: info.first_name,
         lastName: info.last_name,
         address: info.address
        })
      )
    )
    })
```

Comment: Shouldn't that use `Users.users.map` ?

Comment: @Rohit Singh Thanks for answering. This will not work. It gives me 2 `undefined` in console.